# Jmeter test plan does not add user data to a db

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan that simulates a user creation use case. Everything works except when writing to the database. I am trying to figure out why

Comment: What do you mean by 'everything works'? do you see the new user you created in your application?

Comment: I guess every thing works is not the right term. I verify via application logs that all actions up to the user creation work but the user is not created in the DB. Ive looked in the logs and I see no SQL errors.